# Difference between mktime and timelocal

Tags: c, linux, macos, timezone, mktime

What is the difference between these two functions? It was my understanding that those should be the same: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html.

I wrote this code to test the conversion (the Qt part is only for comparison):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDateTime>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   QDateTime datetime(QDate(2012, 3, 25), QTime(5, 15));
   qDebug("Timestamp: %lld.", datetime.toMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000L);

   time_t timestamp;
   tm* timeinfo = localtime(&timestamp);
   timeinfo->tm_hour = 5;
   timeinfo->tm_mday = 25;
   timeinfo->tm_min  = 15;
   timeinfo->tm_mon  = 2;
   timeinfo->tm_year = 112;
   timeinfo->tm_sec  = 0;
   qDebug("Timestamp: %ld.", timelocal(timeinfo));

   return 0;
}
```

and found out that the output is:

```
Timestamp: 1332645300.
Timestamp: 1332645300.
```

which is what I'd expect. Then I replaced `timelocal` with `mktime` and found out that this was the output:

```
Timestamp: 1332645300.
Timestamp: 1332648900.
```

It seems like an hour was added (consider that my current timezone is GMT+2:00 and my locale is set to Italy). Why? What is the difference between the two and why `mktime` adds 1 hour to the date I set?

**EDIT**: I tested again and it seems that on Mac OS X (and iOS) `timelocal` is returning the same hour placed in the `timeinfo` structure, while `mktime` is actually adding an hour both in the returned `time_t` value and in the structure `tm`.

On Linux Kubuntu instead, with both functions I get that an hour is added to both the `tm` structure and the returned value.

Anyone who can explain why?

Comment: I compiled with C++ compiler.

Comment: But you tagged it as C, so be consistent. Now, I've [run your code](http://ideone.com/M7Ik7) and it seems that the results are the same...

Comment: I added some details to my question. What platform where you running?

Comment: It was compiled and run on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/clone/M7Ik7) (gcc 4.3.4)

Comment: Ok, so still the question remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The man of OpenBSD's [`timelocal`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/OpenBSD/man3/timelocal.3.html) states:

> `timelocal` is a deprecated interface that is equivalent to calling
>   `mktime()` with a negative value for `tm_isdst`

A negative value for `tm_isdst` means that `timelocal` doesn't take daylight saving time (DST) into account. It seems that `QDateTime` has troubles with DST as well.
[`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) on the other hand, handles DST and this might explain the 1-hour difference on OS X.

Since `timelocal` is deprecated, it might have newer imlementations that deal with DST properly.